# All jquery validation rules working properly (working onkeyup) but only confirm password validation working only after onclick on submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

On registration form, all jquery validation rules working properly (working onkeyup) but only confirm password validation working only after `onclick` on submit button

confirm password should also work on `onkeyup`, but not happening like others fields

All jquery validation rules working properly (working onkeyup) but only confirm password validation working only after `onclick` on submit button

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script>

  $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#signup').validate({

        rules: {
            "first_name": {
              required: {
                    depends:function(){
                        $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
                        return true;
                    }
              }
            },
            "last_name": {
              required: {
                    depends:function(){
                        $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
                        return true;
                    }
              }
            },
            "mobile_no": {
              required: {
                    depends:function(){
                        $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
                        return true;
                    }
              },
              minlength: 10,
              maxlength: 10,
              digits: true
            },
            "email": {
              required: {
                    depends:function(){
                        $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
                        return true;
                    }
              },
              email: true
            },
            "password": { 
              required: true,
              minlength: 4,
              maxlength: 4,
              digits: true
            },
            "conf_password": {
              required: true,
              equalTo: "#mainpassword"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "first_name": {
              required: "First Name is required"
            },
            "last_name": {
              required: "Last Name is required"
            },
            "mobile_no": {
              required: "Mobile No is required",
              minlength: "Mobile No should be a 10-digit number",
              maxlength: "Mobile No should be a 10-digit number",
              digits: "Mobile No should contain only numbers"
            },
            "email": {
              required: "Email is required",
              email: "Invalid email Id"
            },
            "password": {
              required: "Password is required",
              minlength: "Password should be a 4-digit number",
              maxlength: "Password should be a 4-digit number",
              digits: "Password should contain only numbers"
            },
            "conf_password": {
              required: "Confirm Password is required",
              equalTo: "Password mismatch"
            }
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Some part of HTML code:

```
 ....
    ....
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Password :</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="mainpassword" placeholder="Enter Password" value="<?=set_value('password')?>">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="conf_password" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Confirm Password :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="Password" class="form-control" name="conf_password" id="conf_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" value="<?=set_value('conf_password')?>">
                    </div>
        </div>
    ....
    ....
```

Thanks,

Comment: Could you share the corresponding HTML code as well?

Comment: plz check edit, plz suggest me changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem in this line,

```
<input type="Password" class="form-control" name="conf_password" id="conf_password"  
 placeholder="Confirm Password" value="<?=set_value('conf_password')?>">
```

Change it to

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="conf_password" 
id="conf_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" value="<?=set_value('conf_password')?>">
```

If you notice there is problem with `Password` type which was troubling you, change it to `password`. It will work.

In jqueryvalidation library, it is validating with `[type='password']` and not `[type='Password']` which is the reason it was not reflecting as you want.

Please see below demo for the same.

```js
$.validator.setDefaults({
  submitHandler: function() {
    alert("submitted!");
  }
});

$().ready(function() {
  // validate the comment form when it is submitted
  

  // validate signup form on keyup and submit
  $("#signup").validate({
    rules: {
      
      password: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 4,
        maxlength: 4,
        digits: true
      },
      conf_password: {
        required: true,
              equalTo: "#mainpassword"
      },
      
    },
    messages: {
      
      password: {
        required: "Password is required",
              minlength: "Password should be a 4-digit number",
              maxlength: "Password should be a 4-digit number",
              digits: "Password should contain only numbers"
      },
      conf_password: {
        required: "Confirm Password is required",
              equalTo: "Password mismatch"
      },
      
    }
  });

  // propose username by combining first- and lastname
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form class="cmxform" id="signup" name="signup" method="get" action="">
  <fieldset>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Password :</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="mainpassword" placeholder="Enter Password" value="">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="conf_password" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Confirm Password :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="conf_password" id="conf_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" value="">
                    </div>
        </div>
        
    
    <p>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```